# Replace single quote to regular abbreviation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a state column. Inside the state column I have a value like TX` I want to replace that ending character to make the State read TX. How would I do that please give examples

Comment: Have you tried anything? I can think of about 10 ways to do this off the top of my head. Left, substring, replace are the most likely. I have to ask though, how did you get three characters in a field designed to hold the state abbreviation? Shouldn't that be a char(2)?

Answer (score 1):

You already have answers for replacing the quote, but I wanted to provide methods for avoiding this problem in the first place.

As noted in @SeanLange's answer, you can use define your State field as a `CHAR(2)` , so you know that you'll never have a dummy character following a valid state code. You could also handle this in your client code, sanitizing the input before even sending to the database.

One could argue that it would even be a good idea to define a lookup table with a foreign key constraint, so users could only input valid values. You could also use this lookup table client-side (e.g. to provide a list of states).

Of course, you also have to consider internationalization: What about when/if you need to store locations outside of the United States, that may have > 2 characters?

Answer (score 0):

You can escape a single quote by doubling it and including it in quotes.  So:

```
select replace(state, '''', ''')
```

Of course, if the problem is just a bad third character, then `LEFT(state, 2)` might do the trick as well.

Answer (score 0):

As a Sean Lang's comment said, you can do this in many different ways. For simplicity, you can just use LEFT(string, #) function for the whole typecasting as long as your raw values are all in the **TX` format (**two letter abbrev and one `** , so three characters total for every value in that field.

If that is the case then just do:

```
    SELECT CAST(LEFT(t.state_column, 2) As Varchar(2)) As state, 
           t.column_2, 
           t.column_3 
           /* and so on for all the columns you want */ 
    FROM table t;
```

--

- Further Reference:
  - https://w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/left-function.php